# iDRAC9: The disk ID returned by "get storage.physicalDisk" cannot be recognized for boot sequence

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, drac

I'm using iDRAC9 (v5.10.10.00) on PowerEdge R750.

`get storage.physicalDisk` shows it has a disk `AHCI.SL.6-1`:

```
racadm>> get storage.physicalDisk
Storage.physicalDisk.1 [Key=Disk.Bay.0:Enclosure.Internal.0-1#PhysicalDisk]
Storage.physicalDisk.2 [Key=Disk.Bay.1:Enclosure.Internal.0-1#PhysicalDisk]
Storage.physicalDisk.3 [Key=Disk.Direct.0-0:AHCI.SL.6-1#PhysicalDisk]
```

But `AHCI.SL.6-1` cannot be recognized when setting `UefiBootSeq`:

```
racadm>> set BIOS.UefiBootSettings.UefiBootSeq AHCI.SL.6-1
ERROR: BOOT016: Input source argument value for the boot device is incorrect or
        not found among the boot devices on the system.
```

Instead I must use `AHCI.SL.6-2`:

```
racadm>> set BIOS.UefiBootSettings.UefiBootSeq AHCI.SL.6-2
[Key=BIOS.Setup.1-1#UefiBootSettings]
RAC1017: Successfully modified the object value and the change is in
       pending state.
       To apply modified value, create a configuration job and reboot
       the system. To create the commit and reboot jobs, use "jobqueue"
       command. For more information about the "jobqueue" command, see RACADM
       help.
```

So how can I get the "correct" disk ID `AHCI.SL.6-2` with racadm commands?

Comment: Just tried that out myself on an R7525 and got the same results. I'm guessing that's a BOSS drive you're looking at?

Comment: yes. from idrac web ui it has `BOSS-S2 / AHCI controller in SL 6` on the Storage page.

Comment: I have asked about this internal to Dell. It looks like a bug in how racadm for how this command is handling the BOSS card. Will report back with what I find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000198504/boot-device-fqdd-name-changed-in-15g-bios-uefi-boot-sequence-after-bios-update

To summarize, they used to use the fully qualified device descriptor (FQDD) to identify a storage controller in the UEFI boot sequence. The problem with that is you could have a regular RAID card that had multiple virtual disks that were bootable. Ex - you could end up with something like this:

```
racadm>>racadm get BIOS.biosbootsettings.uefibootseq
[Key=BIOS.Setup.1-1#biosbootsettings]
UefiBootSeq=RAID.SL.8-1,RAID.SL.8-1,NIC.PxeDevice.1-1,NIC.HttpDevice.1-1,Floppy.iDRACVirtual.1-1,Optical.iDRACVirtual.1-1,AHCI.Slot.4-2
```

You have two instances of RAID.SL.8-1 which doesn't work. So what they did is take the FQDD and then specified the bootable disk volume in the sequence **starting with** 2. I'm not sure why they decided to start at 2 but they did. Subsequently, since your BOSS card is running RAID 1 (I assume) and it has a single bootable virtual disk - you end up getting only `AHCI.SL.6-2` as being valid. Since you looked at the physical disks it is returning just the FQDD.

If you do `get bios.uefiBootSettings.UefiBootSeq` then you will correctly see `AHCI.SL.6-2`. Ex on my box:

```
racadm>>get bios.uefiBootSettings.UefiBootSeq
[Key=BIOS.Setup.1-1#uefiBootSettings]
UefiBootSeq=AHCI.SL.7-2,NIC.PxeDevice.1-1
```